# Overfull in vbox inside hbox with hsize of the same width

Tags: tex-core, boxes, plain-tex

While learning with Plain TeX, I am trying to create a framed paragraph.
I have started with the following code, which is supposed to limit the paragraph width but still enable the line breaking mechanism to work correctly (so I can later use `\vline` and `\hline` to create the frame):

```
\hbox to 10cm{
    \vbox{
        \hsize 10cm
        test
    }
}
\bye
```

When I use this code, I get an overfull `\hbox` error

```
Overfull \hbox (4.44443pt too wide) detected at line 6
 [] |
```

When I use longer text, it is correctly divided into individual lines of the width 10 cm.

Why is there an overfull? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way: Spaces or line breaks after braces `{` and `}` are not ignored. You need to use `%` to defeat that:

```
\hbox to 10cm{%
    \vbox{%
        \hsize 10cm
        test
    }%
}%
\bye
```

This generates no overfull messages.

Likewise, putting all the code on one line (which generally I don't advise) -- with no spaces or line breaks after either `{` or `}` -- will also prevent the problem:

```
\hbox to 10cm{\vbox{\hsize10cm test}}%
\bye
```

Comment: Thank you, I absolutely forgot about line breaks being interpreted spaces as well